# How to change default GMT timezone of php 5.4 application on OpenShift?

Tags: php, timezone, openshift

I recently subscribed to OpenShift and deployed a new php 5.4 application, everything works fine, but I can't seem to change the default GMT php timezone.

Here's where this GMT timezone is defined:

> > grep timezone ~/php/configuration/etc/php.ini
>
> date.timezone = GMT

I'm able to edit this php.ini file and update the timezone to my desired value (America/Montreal), but as soon as the php cartridge is restarted (simply by doing a git push or issuing 'ctl_app restart' command on the server for ex), there's an unknown process that restores the php.ini back to openshift factory defaults, so I loose my changes and the timezone is back to GMT.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ini_set()` to modify `php.ini` settings at run time. The modification will be valid only for the current run.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'america/new_york');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'europe/london');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'america/sao_paulo');
... etc.
```

This setting will affect behaviour of date and time functions like `date()`.

Here is a [list of supported timezones](https://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: I would like to know from someone @OpenShift whether the php.ini file being restored to defaults all the time (..but at the same time, it is writable) is a bug or not, and if there is a more permanent way of updating it, instead of having to hack my application code. However, to help others, **you're answer does fix my problem**, thanks. I am using Yii framework (but could have been something else), and added that ini_set() command inside my root/main index.php file that gets called on every request, which is stored in ~/php on redhat OpenShift.

Comment: I too would like @openshift to shed some light on their writable php.ini file that resets after required restart. seems pointless. There is no explanation on the method they advice to edit the php.ini file. since its our app, we should be able to alter the configuration with shell access. whats the problem? Why no documentation?